# Exception on row update

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm getting the exception:

> 09-17 09:49:05.424: ERROR/Database(5971): Error updating
>   suggest_text_1=Testttttttt suggest_text_2=null using UPDATE
>   FTStitleslist SET suggest_text_1=?, suggest_text_2=? WHERE
>   suggest_text_1=Test 09-17 09:49:05.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5971):
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Test: , while compiling: UPDATE FTStitleslist SET suggest_text_1=?,
>   suggest_text_2=? WHERE suggest_text_1=Test
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native
>   Method)

When I execute the method:

```
public void updateTitle(String oldTitle, String newTitle) {
            ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
            newValues.put(KEY_WORD, newTitle);
            newValues.put(KEY_DEFINITION, "null");

            getWritableDatabase().update(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, newValues, KEY_WORD + "=" + oldTitle, null);
        }
```

for the db created like:

```
private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                        " USING fts3 (" +
                        KEY_WORD + ", " +
                        KEY_DEFINITION + ");";
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text values must be enclosed in single quotes:

```
'Test'
```

If they are not, the compiler will try to interpret the value (i.e. Test) as a column name.

From the exception message:

```
WHERE suggest_text_1=Test
```